# Flask SQLAlchemy Foreign Key Relationships

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm having a lot of trouble getting my head around foreign keys and relationships in SQLAlchemy. I have two tables in my database. The first one is `Request` and the second one is `Agent`. Each `Request` contains one `Agent` and each `Agent` has one `Request`.

```
class Request(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'request'
    reference = db.Column(db.String(10), primary_key=True)
    applicationdate = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    agent = db.ForeignKey('request.agent'),

class Agent(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'agent'
    id =     db.relationship('Agent', backref='request', \
    lazy='select')
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    company = db.Column(db.String(80))
    address = db.Column(db.String(180))
```

When I am running `db.create_all()` I get the following error

> Could not initialize target column for ForeignKey 'request.agent' on table 'applicant': table 'request' has no column named 'agent'

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Have a look at the [SqlAlchemy documentation on OneToOne relationships](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-one). First you need to supply a `Primary Key` for each model. Then you need to define one `Foreign Key` which refers to the `Primary Key` of the other model. Now you can define a relationship with a backref that allows direct access to the related model.

```
class Request(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'request'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    applicationdate = db.Column(db.DateTime)

class Agent(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'agent'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)   
    request_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('request.id'))
    request = db.relationship("Request", backref=backref("request", uselist=False))

    name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    company = db.Column(db.String(80))
    address = db.Column(db.String(180))
```

Now you can access your models like this:

```
request = Request.query.first()
print(request.agent.name)

agent = Agent.query.first()
print(agent.request.applicationdate)
```

Comment: In this case, the following 2 lines should look like this:

`request_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('request.id'))` and `request = db.relationship("Request", backref=db.backref("request", uselist=False))`

because the database is imported as `db`.

Comment: but @MrLeeh, would you please tell me, why backref = "request" , and not "Request"?

Comment: The table name is „request“. This is what you need to pass here.