# SQLalchemy query not updating relationship columns in put api

Tags: python-3.x, api, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have a model.py with a class Histogram and a table histogram_axes -

```
histograms_axes = Table(
    "histograms_axes",
    _ORMBase.metadata,
    Column("histogram_id", ForeignKey("histograms.id"), primary_key=True),
    Column("axis_id", ForeignKey("axes.id"), primary_key=True),
)

class Histogram(Base):
    block = Column(Integer)
    num = Column(Integer)
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("s.id"))

    axes = relationship(
        "Axis", secondary=histograms_axes, backref="histograms", order_by="asc(Axis.name)"
    )
```

I have written a put API in FastAPI to update the rows based on id, but it only updates the columns not the relationship in Histogram class.

```
@router.put("/histograms")
def put_histograms(response: HistogramSchema, id: int, axes: List[int], db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    histogram = db.query(Histogram).filter(Histogram.id == id)
    if not histogram.first():
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail=f"Histogram id {id} is not found!")
    histogram.axes = db.query(Axis).filter(Axis.id.in_(axes)).all()
    response = response.dict(exclude_unset=True)
    histogram.update(response)
    db.commit()
    return histogram.one_or_none()
```

How can I update the relationship table as well.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41569395/7573951) from @MrLeeh might help you

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help in my case.

Comment: `but it only updates the columns not the relationship in Histogram class.` how do you test?

Comment: I have tested in swagger UI. It only updates the columns @MikkoOhtamaa